# Getting a new outgoing Amazon EC2 IP

Tags: amazon-web-services

If I want to change my outgoing Amazon EC2 IP, what's the best way to do that?  Should I just destroy the instance and create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an elastic IP and attach it to your VM. As long as the IP is attached to and EC2-instance it's very cheap/free.